# How to implement a function with non overlapping and rolling features simultaneously in Pandas/Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I need to perform a cumulative return calculation over a window where the function restarts at the beginning of the next window. Let's look at an example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108],
                 columns=['A'], index=[range(1,10)])
```

Say you define your window size to be 3, given that I need the cumulative returns of the window, the desired output would be

```
A['B'] = function(A['A'], window=3)

      A         B
1   100         0
2   101  0.010000
3   102  0.020000
4   103         0
5   104  0.009709
6   105  0.019417
7   106         0
8   107  0.009434
9   108  0.018868
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do this with a `groupby`:

```
>>> w = 3
>>> A["B"] = A.groupby(np.arange(len(A))//w)["A"].apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0]-1)
>>> A
     A         B
1  100  0.000000
2  101  0.010000
3  102  0.020000
4  103  0.000000
5  104  0.009709
6  105  0.019417
7  106  0.000000
8  107  0.009434
9  108  0.018868
```