# In Pandas/Numpy, How to implement a rolling function inside each chunk using 2 different columns?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I have a df that is 'divided' by chunks, like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 2, 0], [2, 4, 4, 0], [3, 3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 2, 0], [5, 1, 4, 0], [2, 4, 4, 1]],
                columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,])
```

In this example, the chunk size is 3, and we have 2 chunks (signaled by the element 1 in the column 'D'). I need to perfom a rolling calculation **inside each chunk**, that involves 2 columns. Specifically, I need to create a column 'E' that is equal to column 'B' minus the rolling min of column 'C', in function:

```
def retracement(x):
    return x['B'] - pd.rolling_min(x['C'], window=3)
```

I need to apply the formula above for each chunk. So [following this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879735/how-to-implement-a-function-with-non-overlapping-and-rolling-features-simultaneo) I tried:

```
chunk_size = 3
A['E'] = A.groupby(np.arange(len(A))//chunk_size).apply(lambda x: retracement(x))

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

The output would look like:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
1  1  5  2  0  3    
2  2  4  4  0  2   
3  3  3  1  1  2    
4  4  2  2  0  0    
5  5  1  4  0 -1    
6  2  4  4  1  2
```

Thanks

**Update:**

Following @EdChum recommendation didn't work, I got

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Comment: You just need to add the param `axis=1`:  apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)` then whatever your func does access the columns of interest : `def func(x):  return x['A'] + x['C']` as an example

Comment: @EdChum I followed your recommendation, still stuck there.

Comment: I think what's happening is the result of the apply() is a DataFrame with 2 rows and 3 columns not a Series with 6 elements.  Try adding `.values.flatten()` to the end of your command.  I don't know if this gives you what you want though... your rolling min doesn't give you the numbers you specify in your desired output (maybe you just want min() in that function?)

Comment: @Ajean the solution you propose gives what I want, but only for the last element of each chunk. Not on a rolling basis. For the rest gives NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
def chunkify(chunk_size):
    df['chunk'] = (df.index.values - 1) / chunk_size
    df['E'] = df.groupby('chunk').apply(lambda x: x.B - pd.expanding_min(x.C)).values.flatten()
```