# How to implement non overlapping rolling functionality on MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So far I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879735/how-to-implement-a-function-with-non-overlapping-and-rolling-features-simultaneo) but it doesn't solve my problem due to the facts that:

1. I have a MultiIndex DataFrame
2. The inner level has different amount of data for each outer level, thus I can't use `len()`

I have the following DataFrame

```
Outer Inner    Value        
  A     1     2.000000
  A     2     4.000000
  A     3     6.000000
  A     4     8.000000
  B     1     3.000000
  B     2     6.000000
  B     3     9.000000
  B     4     12.000000
  B     5     15.000000
```

I want to sum the last two values for each `outer` in a non-overlapping manner. So for `A` I want to sum `inner`'s 3 + 4, 1 + 2. For `B` I want to sum `inner`'s 4 + 5, 2 + 3. Note that the pairwise sum is supposed to start from the last value. Resulting in

```
Outer Inner    Value        
  A     2     6.000000
  A     4    14.000000
  B     3    15.000000
  B     5    27.000000
```

Comment: What happens to `B1`?

Comment: I guess it gets discarded because there is no group of 2. but any other handling is acceptable.

Comment: So you start summing up the pairs from the last value? I would have thought that B5 is the one who should be discarded

Comment: oh makes sense. But ideally I'd like to start from the last and leave B1 out.

Comment: but what's the logic there? How can you start from the start and leave B1 out?

Comment: Do you care about keeping the `Inner` index numbers exactly the same after?

Comment: I made it preserve `Inner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Groupby with custom resample function

You will most likely need custom resampling to do this.  It is a little *hacky* but might work.

1. Remove all `MulitIndex`ing to deal with just regular column `groupby()`s
2. [`groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) `'Outer'` and [`.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) a custom function to each group
3. The custom function takes a group

   1. Determine the even length of the group
   2. Select that length backwards
   3. Turn index into seconds
   4. Resample the DataFrame every two samples by [`resample(...)`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#resampling)`.sum()`
   5. Resample the `Inner` column every two by [`resample(...)`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#resampling)`.last()` to preserve original index numbers
   6. Convert index back to '`Inner'`
4. Even though we removed the `MultiIndex`, a `MultiIndex` is still returned by `groupby(...).apply()`

Note:
There is an issue with [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows), as it *slides* thru the values instead of *stepping thru* the values (in a non-overlapping method). Using [`resample`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#resampling) allows this.  Resample is time based the index needs to be represented as seconds.

#### Example

```
import math
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Outer': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
    'Inner': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5],
    'Value': [2.00,4.00,6.00,8.00,3.00,6.00,9.00,12.00,15.00]
})

def f(g):
    even_length = int(2.0 * math.floor(len(g) / 2.0))
    every_two_backwards = g.iloc[-even_length:]
    every_two_backwards.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(every_two_backwards.index * 1000000000.0)
    resample_via_sum = every_two_backwards.resample('2s').sum().dropna()
    resample_via_sum['Inner'] = every_two_backwards.resample('2s').last()
    resample_via_sum = resample_via_sum.set_index('Inner')

    return resample_via_sum

resampled_df = df.groupby(['Outer']).apply(f)

print resampled_df
```

---

```
             Value
Outer Inner       
A     2.0      6.0
      4.0     14.0
B     3.0     15.0
      5.0     27.0
```

Comment: just one question , what does ``'2s`` mean ? I'm adapting the function for other intervals to test

Comment: `'2s'` just means to resample by 2 seconds.

Comment: Since we turned the index into seconds to use `resample` we resample in *seconds*

Comment: If you want to step 5, you'd resample by `'5s'` or 5 seconds

Comment: Does that make sense?  Remember to change is in *both* places.  You might want to make it a variable (`resample_step = '2s'`) so you can reference it in both places.  e.g. `resample(resample_step)`.

Comment: what about the 2.0 * math.floor for instance, should I change it there also ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change it there. That is just for determining the even length of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, roll up your sleeve, this takes a bit of work:

```
new_level0 = []
new_level1 = []
new_values  = []

for level0 in df.index.levels[0].values:
    #this will loop with A and B

    #retrieve the values
    level1_values = df[level0]['Value'].values
    #retrieve the index, we will keep some of the values of it
    level1_index  = df[level0].index.values


    #split the values into two vectors
    #reverse so that it starts pairing values from the end
    level1_even = [i for enum,i in enumerate(level1_values) if enum%2==0].reverse()
    level1_odd =  [i for enum,i in enumerate(level1_values) if enum%2==1].reverse()
    #
    #
    #sum and reverse again to bring back to normal order
    summed = [i+j for i,j in zip(level1_even,level1_odd)]
    summed.reverse()
    #
    #
    #now that we have the values, lets get the index that we need
    #again, reverse so that we keep the right one
    level1_index.reverse()

    #keep only the multiples of two, then undo the reverse
    new_index = [i for enum,i in enumerate(level1_values) if enum%2==0].reverse()

    #now store the combination of level0, level1 and value
    new_level0 += [level0 for i in summed]
    new_level1 += new_index
    new_values += summed

    #your final structure is:
    s = pd.Series(summed, index= [new_level0, new_level1])
```